# Totally Disable Java 8 Security

Tags: windows-8, java, security-policy

Ever since Java 8, running java requires going through the java control panel, adding an exception to the site list, and restarting firefox.  And even with an exception in the site list, it still prompts for permission to run.

Is it possible to skip the site list step, enabling java for all web sites?

(I know that, technically, a website can have a java app that can run without creating an exception, but I have yet to find a website that actually does it.)

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Java 8 U 20 Security Prompts](http://superuser.com/questions/820158/disable-java-8-u-20-security-prompts)